# Is it possible to avoid duplicate storage of a ContractState if it does not evolve in a Transaction?

Tags: corda

I have two different implementations of net.corda.core.contracts.ContractState, say StateA and StateB, to model two different types of on-ledger facts. At some point I want to evolve an instance of StateA. An update to StateA is only sensible in connection with an instance of StateB, so the Contract referenced by StateA has to be able to evaluate both StateA and StateB together. The StateB that is required in order to update StateA however does not evolve at this point. StateA and StateB are modeled as disjoint entities because StateB might also change at some other point in time, independently of StateA.

At the moment I am creating a Transaction with both StateA and StateB as inputs, and the evolved StateA' and the same StateB as the outputs, which enables me to access both StateA and StateB in StateA's Contract's verify()-function. After the transaction is validated, I can see two rows with identical versions of StateB persisted as serialized objects into the VAULT_STATES table (column CONTRACT_STATE). While this is somewhat expected given that StateB was consumed and re-created by the Transaction, it seems wasteful to store multiple copies of the same value just in order to access/evaluate it in a Contract. Is there a way to avoid this behavior ? I am hesitating to provide StateB via a Transaction-Command because its validity should also be guaranteed when verifying the Transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great question. What you are observing is indeed expected. In the majority of cases, if one adds an input and output state to a transaction there is an expectation that the output will differ from the input in some way.

Clearly though, in your use-case, no change is required! There are two options I see:

1. Do nothing. I agree that the duplication of the data is sub-optimal. However, state objects are never usually that large in memory terms, so the duplication should never become an issue.
2. If the data in State B only ever needs to be created once and never updated then you can use an attachment to store this data. The advantage of using this approach is that attachments are never consumed and they are still accessible to the `verify()` function. If the data DOES need to evolve then potentially you could update the attachment and then re-attach it to your transaction, thus superseding the previous transaction.

Comment: Thanks! I had not considered the attachment-option and it's good for me to be aware of it. For my specific use-case I have now realized that not everyone who will see the transaction may/should necessarily be able to see the actual StateB, but rather some assertion over it. So instead of making the actual StateB the transaction-input, I will explore how to model the assertion, make that a transaction-input (probably as a command), and use an oracle-service (which does see the StateB) to sign for it.